# Win-app calling a webservice vs. web-app calling the same service

Tags: .net, web-services

I am trying to consume data from a webservice published by a 3rd party.  I have a SDK win-app that is able to call the service (from my dev machine) and get results, but a web-app (running on the same machine) which has the same code, is getting nothing back.

My question is:

Is there a difference (from the server's prospective) as to what type of app calls the web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. To the server it is just a request.  Both apps communicate with it through HTTP and SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin said, to the server it's just a request.

I would recommend running [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) to see what's happening at a network level. Then you can see whether the problem is that the client is sending a different type of request which the server can't understand, or whether the server is sending back information but the client can't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Make sure your web-app isn't hitting a firewall rule trying to make the outbound web request. Also make sure the user you're running your web-app as has sufficient permissions to make the web service request.